# Xcode Storyboards - iPhone 7 Plus has no status bar?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

Why does the iPhone 7 Plus storyboard have no Status Bar visible in Xcode where as the other sizes do (iPhone 7, 5s). When running the app in the iPhone 7 Plus it has a status bar but on the storyboard it doesn't?

iPhone 7 Plus and has no status bar:
[image: iPhone 7 Plus]

iPhone 7 storyboard that has status bar:
[image: iPhone 7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

closing xcode and and then opening it helped me. It was messing with the storyboard but only in the iphone 7 plus for me.

Comment: Yeah, I have since experienced it again and I just close Xcode and open it again, it's only the plus models for me too. I think it must be a bug. I will log it with apple

Comment: I have yet to experience the issue more than the one time. I have also updated my Xcode to 8.3.3, no issue there either.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the status bar was disabled on that size class for some reason:

[image]

If that is so, change it to 'inferred' and that should fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately not, if I start a brand new project it happens as soon as I switch to iPhone 7 plus in the storyboard view

Answer (score 0):

So, uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling it has fixed this issue

Comment: I don't think it's a problem in xcode. I just created a new project and status bar is there on every device.